# Find bootstrapped confidence interval with bootstrapped library

Tags: python, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

So let's imagine I have an array of sample data which is normally distributed. What I want, is to compute the probability of another sample being less than -3 and provide a bootstrapped confidence interval for that probability. After doing some research, I found the `bootstrapped` python library which I want to use to find the CI.

So I have:

```
import numpy as np
import bootstrapped.bootstrap as bs
import bootstrapped.stats_functions as bs_stats
mu, sigma = 2.5, 4 # mean and standard deviation
samples = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
bs.bootstrap(samples, stat_func= ???)
```

What should I write for stat_func ? I tried writing a lambda function to compute the probability of -3, but it did not work. I know how to compute the probability of a sample being less than -3, it's simply the CI which I am having a hard time dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the example of `stat_functions.mean` from the `bootstrapped` package. Below it is wrapped in a 'factory' so that you can specify the level at which you want to calculate the frequency (sadly you cannot pass it as an optional argument to functions that `bootstrap()` is expecting). Basically `prob_less_func_factory(level)` returns a function that calculates the proportion of your sample that is less than that `level`. It can be used for matrices just like the example I followed.

```
def prob_less_func_factory(level = -3.0):
    def prob_less_func(values, axis=1):
        '''Returns the proportion of samples that are less than the 'level' of each row of a matrix'''
        return np.mean(np.asmatrix(values)<level, axis=axis).A1
    return prob_less_func
```

Now you pass it in like so

```
level = -3
bs_res = bs.bootstrap(samples, stat_func = prob_less_func_factory(level=level))
```

and the result I get (yours will be slightly different because `samples` is random) is

```
0.088    (0.06999999999999999, 0.105)
```

so the `boostrap` function estimated (well, calculated) the proportion of values in `samples` that are less than `-3` to be `0.088` and the confidence interval around it is `(0.06999999999999999, 0.105)`

For checking we can calculate the theoretical value of one sample from your distribution being less than `-3`:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
print(f'Theoretical Prob(N(mean={mu},std={sigma})<{level}): {norm.cdf(level, loc=mu,scale =sigma)}')
```

and we get

```
Theoretical Prob(N(mean=2.5,std=4)<-3): 0.08456572235133569
```

so it all seems consistent consistent.